# Group_by if overlap

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by, overlap

I would like to know how to group lines with coordinates overlapping.

I'm trying to merge overlaps based in coordinates in a segment (line).

For example, I have:

```
tibble(
  target = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "c"),
  query  = c("D", "D", "D", "D", "E", "D", "D", "E", "E"),
  start  = c(  3,  10,  30,   8,  16,   7,   9,  16,  25),
  end    = c( 12,  15,  45,  15,  20,  12,  14,  32,  31)
) -> d
```

or

```
# A tibble: 9 x 4
  target query start   end
  <chr>  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 a      D         3    12
2 a      D        10    15
3 a      D        30    45
4 b      D         8    15
5 b      E        16    20
6 c      D         7    12
7 c      D         9    14
8 c      E        16    32
9 c      E        25    31
```

The pair target query is a mapping of equals regions between both, but sometimes the pair has more than one matches when it happens the matches might have overlap.

So, I'm trying to do this way

```
> d %>%
+   group_by(target, query) %>%
+   arrange(start,end) %>%
+   summarise(
+     start = min(start),
+     end = max(end)
+   )
# A tibble: 5 x 4
# Groups:   target [?]
  target query start   end
  <chr>  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 a      D         3    45
2 b      D         8    15
3 b      E        16    20
4 c      D         7    14
5 c      E        16    32
```

As you can see, the output is wrong. Somehow I think I should group by the lines with overlap, but I don't know how to do it.

The expected output is:

```
  target query start   end
  <chr>  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 a      D         3    15
2 a      D        30    45
3 b      D         8    15
4 b      E        16    20
5 c      D         7    14
6 c      E        16    32
```

This kind of `goup_by` using overlap must be used to other approaches.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
d %>% 
  group_by(target, query) %>%
  arrange(start) %>%
  group_by(index = cumsum(cummax(lag(end, default = first(end))) < start), target, query) %>%
  summarise(start = first(start), end = max(end)) %>%
  arrange(target)
```

Gives the following output:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 5
# Groups:   index, target [4]
  index target query start   end
  <int> <chr>  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1     0 a      D         3    15
2     1 a      D        30    45
3     0 b      D         8    15
4     0 b      E        16    20
5     0 c      D         7    14
6     0 c      E        16    32
```

You can then go ahead and get rid of the `index` column if you don't need it.

Comment: Would you mind in explain this `group_by`. But anyway, thanks

Comment: Sure. `lag(end, default = first(end))` starts by looking at the previous `end` value. `cummax` then takes the maximum value of these lagged values. We then compare these lagged values to the `start` values, and get `TRUE` if the value is less than `start`, which implies that this is a new interval and not an overlapping one. If we get `FALSE` it means the intervals overlap. Wrapping this in `cumsum` just allows you to get index values that you can group by. Now each unique interval has a different `index` value you can associate with, and we can get our new intervals with `summarise`

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect use case for [ivs](https://davisvaughan.github.io/ivs/), a package for working with intervals. The `iv_groups()` function will merge all the overlapping intervals and return the remaining intervals.

```r
library(ivs)
library(dplyr)

tibble(
  target = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "c"),
  query  = c("D", "D", "D", "D", "E", "D", "D", "E", "E"),
  start  = c(  3,  10,  30,   8,  16,   7,   9,  16,  25),
  end    = c( 12,  15,  45,  15,  20,  12,  14,  32,  31)
) -> d

d <- d %>%
  mutate(range = iv(start, end), .keep = "unused")

d
#> # A tibble: 9 × 3
#>   target query     range
#>   <chr>  <chr> <iv<dbl>>
#> 1 a      D       [3, 12)
#> 2 a      D      [10, 15)
#> 3 a      D      [30, 45)
#> 4 b      D       [8, 15)
#> 5 b      E      [16, 20)
#> 6 c      D       [7, 12)
#> 7 c      D       [9, 14)
#> 8 c      E      [16, 32)
#> 9 c      E      [25, 31)

d %>%
  group_by(target, query) %>%
  summarise(range = iv_groups(range), .groups = "drop")
#> # A tibble: 6 × 3
#>   target query     range
#>   <chr>  <chr> <iv<dbl>>
#> 1 a      D       [3, 15)
#> 2 a      D      [30, 45)
#> 3 b      D       [8, 15)
#> 4 b      E      [16, 20)
#> 5 c      D       [7, 14)
#> 6 c      E      [16, 32)
```